Digitwise_addition: exceed limit: if exceeded -> code time out
i am working on a kata.
Digitwise addition is a special kind of addition where instead of adding 1 normally to the number, it adds 1 to every digit of that number. If the digit is a 9, we replace it with a 10 without carrying over to the next digit.
Examples
123 -> 234
Task
Program a function that takes two numbers, n and k, and outputs the number of digits in n after applying Digitwise addition k times. Since the answer can be very large, return the answer modulo 1_000_000_007.
Your solution is expected to be O(klogn).
My solution:
import sys
MOD = 10**9 + 7 

sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)

def d2a(digits):

  arr= list(map(int,str(digits)))
  return arr


def a2d(arr):
  length=len(arr)
  digit=""

  for i in range(length):
    digit+=str(arr[i])
  return int(digit)


def add(n):
  return n+1


def digitwise_addition(digit, K):
  for i in range(K):
    #CONVERTING INTO ARRAY
    arr=d2a(digit)
    #ADDING 1 INTO ALL NUMBERS FROM ARRAY
    arr=list(map(add,arr))
    #CONVERTING ARRAY INTO DIGIT
    digit=a2d(arr)

  arr=d2a(digit)
  return len(arr) %MOD


problem: it passes all the calculations, but when K is large, it asks to exceed limit, and if exceeded, it says: code timeout

O(k log n) requirement looks a bit strange. If your numbers are given as strings, the complexity is O(k + log n) or even better. If the numbers are given in any binary bignum format, the complexity includes at least conversion to decimal, which is worse than O(log n) and not comparable to O(k logn). I think this complexity requirement is trash and you should ignore it.

In your loop the digit string gets longer and longer, and this slows down the process. It makes the time complexity worse than O(log).
You could use this insights:

There are only 10 different cases per digit to deal with when adding 1, so instead of storing every digit separately, you could maintain a count of how many you have of each distinct digit: so you'd have 10 counters.

In every iteration, the number of "2" digits is the same as the number of "1" digits you had before. Similar for the other digits (where the number of "0" becomes the number of "9" you had before), except that the number of "1" is the sum of both the numbers of "0" and "9" you had before.


Here is how that translates into code:
from collections import deque

MOD = 10**9 + 7 

def digitwise_addition(n, k):
    digits = deque([0] * 10)
    for digit in str(n):
        digits[int(digit)] += 1
    for i in range(k):
        digits.rotate()
        digits[1] += digits[0]
            
    return sum(digits) % MOD

Instead of rotating the list digits, we could rotate the index over the list. Secondly, we could apply the modulo operation at every addition so that the complexity of each iteration of the second loop is O(1) once i >= 10.
MOD = 10**9 + 7 

def digitwise_addition(n, k):
    digits = [0] * 10
    for digit in str(n):
        digits[int(digit)] += 1
    for i in range(k):
        i = -i % 10
        digits[i] = (digits[i] + digits[(i-1) % 10]) % MOD
            
    return sum(digits) % MOD

The time complexity is within the limits suggested in the code challenge and the test cases all pass within the time limit.

I might change this to digits[1] = (digits[1] + digits[0]) % MOD.  (This is in addition to the % in the return statement.) The numbers can grow large very quickly/. No harm in pruning them early.

Good point. I have added this to my answer.

You have not indicated how big k is. If k is small, then @trincot's algorithm is great.  But if k is large, you'll want to use an algorithm that's logarithmic in k.
You'll notice that in the first loop of trincot's program, if the queue originally has
D=(d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9) then after one iteration of the loop, the queue will contain D'=(d9, d9+d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8).  This is just a linear combination so it can be accomplished by a matrix multiplication in which D' = M x D.
       | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 |
       | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 |
       | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
       | 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
M =    | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
       | 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 |
       | 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 |
       | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 |
       | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 |
       | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 |

Matrix multiplication is much harder than just shifting the queue and adding two elements. But when k is large, we're calculating
D' = M x M x ...... M x D = (M**k) * D

where M is repeated k times.  But there are fast algorithms for exponentiation that can calculate M**k in log k time.
M ** k = (M ** (k / 2)) ** 2 if k is even
M ** k = M * (M ** (k / 2)) ** 2 if k is odd

Since the elements of M**k can grow large quickly, after each multiplication, we can mod the elements of the array by MOD = 10**9+7.
We can quickly calculate (M**k) * D, and then sum up the digits in the result.
